# how to bind event to element after generateing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script :

```
$(window).load(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-confirm', function () {...});
});
```

and I have this element :

```
<div id="attachments"></div>
```

and I have this script to load some html :

```
    $(document).on('click', '.nav-tabs li a[href="#attach"]', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: loadAttachmentsURL,
        data: { equipmentId: equipmentId },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#attachments").html(data);
        }
    });

});
```

in my result from `ajax` I have some button that have `.btn-delete-confirm` `class`  but when clicked on them nothing happen .
the sample of result like this :

```
<td><a  data-id="73b2db39-199c-845c-8807-6c6164d2d97d" data-url="/Admin/EquipmentAttachment/Delete" class="btn-delete-confirm btn">Delete</a></td>
```

how can I resolve this ?

Comment: show the result from ajax

Comment: **Did you wrote the javascript code follow the html code?**
If you wrote javascript before html code, it maybe cant work

Comment: @ShiranDror updated

Comment: is the click function being called? did you try adding console.log or alert()?

Comment: @ShiranDror after ajax call I add script (that contains click function) to my page .

Comment: Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment. I would like to know which version of jQuery are you using? According to the jQuery documentation, `.live()` could have been used to bind events to future elements, but it has been deprecated. `.delegate()` and `.on()` can be used for this purpose now. I can see that the code you wrote uses `.on()`. This should work fine unless you are not using version 1.7+. [More details here](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: my `jquery` version is `2.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

one way will be by attaching `click` event after html is set:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.nav-tabs li a[href="#attach"]', function() {
      var equipmentId = "?";
      var loadAttachmentsURL = "/url";
      $.ajax({
          url: loadAttachmentsURL,
          data: {
              equipmentId: equipmentId
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $("#attachments").html(data);
              $(".btn-delete-confirm").click(function() {
                  alert("click!");
              });
          }
      });
  });
```

another will be attaching the `click` event to the `document` context:

```
$(document).on('click', ".btn-delete-confirm", function() {
    alert("click!");
});
$(document).on('click', '.nav-tabs li a[href="#attach"]', function() {
    var equipmentId = "?";
    var loadAttachmentsURL = "/url";
    $.ajax({
        url: loadAttachmentsURL,
        data: {
            equipmentId: equipmentId
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#attachments").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an eventlistener to something that isnt there yet.
This will result in an error, and the event wont fire again.

So try to add the listener AFTER the ajax import.

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-tabs li a[href="#attach"]', function () {

$.ajax({
    url: loadAttachmentsURL,
    data: { equipmentId: equipmentId },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#attachments').html(data);
        $('.btn-delete-confirm').on('click', function () {...});
    }
});
```

});

Comment: your answer destroys the elegance of delegation of events for dynamic elements.

Comment: Its not repeating, you should DELETE your evenlistener and only put one after the ajax request....

Answer (score 0):

Though [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method is deprecated in jquery-3.0, its description is still worth to have a look:

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.

**Exmaple:**

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

**Using `document` as a root element is not a big problem, but have you tried  `#attachments` ?**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#attachments").on('click', '.btn-delete-confirm', function () {...});
});
```

Comment: I can't change to `attachment` because other linkes don't in `#attachment`